# Finding Plus Codes that are nearby

Tags: sql, dictionary, geo

I have a small database of points in `Plus Codes` (500 records). I have used Plus Codes for their ability to be rendered on a map whilst offline. I want to be able to query the database to find records within 0.5 miles of point *x*. Is there an algorithm to measure the distance between Plus Codes? Can Plus Codes be easily translated into latitude and longitude? Or am I best storing latitudes and longitudes instead?

Comment: did you find your answer?

Comment: No,  I've not been able to find anything ‍♂️

Comment: This has great info on the formula to convert plus codes to lat/long coordinates: https://www.dcode.fr/open-location-code    And then, look around the Google Maps Platform: https://developers.google.com/maps  (they have a "Nearby Search" based on lat/long, BUT results won't be limited to your 500 point database: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#nearby-search-example)

Answer (score 0):

Plus code is just an alternate notation for latitude and longitude; every plus code can be converted to a set of latitude and longitude coordinates.

The Open Location Code (plus code) [github repo](https://github.com/google/open-location-code) has modules in many languages, so if you use one of them to convert to lat/lng, you can compare distances. I don't think those modules themselves provide any distance-measuring functions.